# My JQuery exist function: does it make sense or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I'm a bit confused the last couple a days. I use my JQUERY selectors whenever I like... but I didn't check whether a selector exist or not, instead I used the .each function.

```
  var exist = function(obj){
    var returnObject ={};
    for(var key in obj){
      if(obj[key].length){
        returnObject[key] = obj[key];
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return returnObject;
  }
  //define all your selectors that would be needed for core functionality.
  var activeSelectors = exist({
    selList : $('div.selectorone'),
    selTag : $('a#tagtwo'),
    selFloat : $(div.float) /*etc etc*/

  }) 

  if (activeSelectors) {
    console.log('all my core selectors are here!');
     /* do Stuff*/
  }
```

I know this looks a bit much, especially if you need only one selector, but I can't figure out a better way (except a lame if statement at every selector). I saw people using

`$('div#mySelector').each(function(){ /* do stuff*/});`

but I don't agree that it's nice. Notice that #mySelector (because it's an id) is only once allowed.

I would love the feedback. Please consider the performance vs Nice programming.

for more info please comment below or contact me!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but `$('div.selectorone').length` will return 0 when it's "empty" so simple `if` statement might be what you're after.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard thanks for your reply. The if statement would work as well, but the code stops after a selector isn't there, so it's stops early in code. And a other thing is if($('sel').length){ $('sel'.css())} i call the DOM twice i could use var but i its like 3 lines of code (performance vs nicely)

Comment: why should the if statement be lame? Most of the jq plugins are based on the each anyway, so an each of a selector thats empty does nothing anyway. I dont see the point in doing this.

Comment: actually this toppic could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266528/generalized-length-check-on-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really wanted to avoid just using a plain `if` statement, then I'd probably just go with a simple function like this:

```
var exists = function()
{
    for (var i in arguments)
    {
        if ($(arguments[i]).length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
var list = $('div.selectorone');
var tag = $('a#tagtwo');
var float = $('div.float');
if (exists(list, tag, float))
{
    // Do some stuff.
}
```

Or:

```
if (exists('div.selectorone', 'a#tagtwo', 'div.float'))
{
    // Do some stuff.
}
```

I do think you're over-engineering the problem though. All you really need to do is check the `length` property on each of the selections you've made (i.e. the `list`, `tag`, `float` variables).

Also, performance is a complete non-issue here; is the method of checking whether the elements exist actually going to affect the user experience for your site? As Donald Knuth said:

> We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil.

Comment: vousden.. also thanks for your reply. I'm not really avoiding the if statement, not at all. i did call it lame because if you use an 'if' statement you do it over and over at every selector. if(sel.length){//go} .. i do want to avoid calling my selector in dom twice. So i do like your function (its a bit smaller) with invoke nr1. but it's basically the same function.. i could remove 1 variable, i agree. Performance a non issue i know but we have to force our self making the best code there is, don't you agree?

Comment: @Mimo: no; performance should not be a consideration until it has to be. Of course, don't write slow code when there's a straightforward alternative that's faster, but don't optimize unless it's necessary. Besides, I would argue that the "best" code is readable and maintainable before it is fast.